# Github Self-Hosted runner registration auth fails in GCE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I am setting up self hosted runner on the Google compute engine by following the steps as advised by GitHub for Enterprise as follows.

```
//Create a folder
$ mkdir actions-runner && cd actions-runner

// Download the latest runner package
$ curl -O -L https://github.com/actions/runner/releases/download/v2.273.5/actions-runner-osx-x64-2.273.5.tar.gz

// Extract the installer
$ tar xzf ./actions-runner-osx-x64-2.273.5.tar.gz
```

And then running the below command to configure the runner.

```
./config.sh --url https://github.entp-api.com/ENTP/mywebsite_repo --token AAAAA4EGUBEEPAUS2HOK4NTCPO7LS
```

After running the cmd above the registration authentication fails as below.

[image]

Error-

```
Http response code: Forbidden from 'POST https://github.entp-api.com/api/v3/actions/runner-registration'
<!doctype html><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><title>403</title>403 Forbidden                              
Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).
```

Comment: Please paste error messages instead of screenshots. This helps people with the same problem in the future find your question.

Comment: updated with error text

Answer (score 1):

I have recently faced same issue. Once you login in Github the token generated will expire "reload the page in Github" you will be given with new token you will not face any issues.